# Any online video tutorials on TEX / LATEX and MathML, and similar other tools for Windows users?

Tags: learning

Is there any repository of online videos on using and mastering TEX / LATEX, and similar other tools for free download?

Comment: *Please*, one question per post. Video tutorial: I'm working on it >:) but it won't be windows-specific. They'll be on YouTube. Accessibility: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47054/17423 http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145367/17423 WinTriangle: never heard of it.

Comment: I would really edit this post to ask *exactly one* answerable question. As it stands, it's unanswerable and likely to be closed.

Comment: Also, edit it so that it focuses on on-topic issues. I don't know what SWP is, but MathML is presumably off-topic. And a general question about tools for maths is probably better asked on Maths SE. No idea what WinTriangle is.