# About duxbury software

Tags: packages, accessibility

I'm working with blind people, particularly I'm teaching maths. Normally when I want to give a paper with exercises to my students I have to do a .pdf document, then change it to .doc and finally then I can print it. That's because duxbury (Braille printer software) only read documents in Word.
The thing is that I've heard about a certain relation about the duxbury software  and LaTeX. Apparently, duxbury can read .tex documents and then print the .pdf document. If it's true, it would be of great help.

Anyone knows about a package in LaTeX that can make that? or knows more than me about duxbury and LaTeX?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: We do have some questions about the braille and LaTeX which might be helpful: [LaTeX to Braille](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32609/2693) and [Producing embossed tactile graphics with Tikz for a student who is blind](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162738/2693).

Answer (score 4):

Off-topic, but perhaps worth mentioning ...

[image: braille document]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braille}
\begin{document}
\braille{{Capital}{do} {you} {know} {that} LaTeX {can} write {braille}?}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the manufacturer*, Duxbury Braille Transator can import many file formats, `.doc` and `.tex` being two of them. There is no package requirement.

*https://www.duxburysystems.com/import.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Duxbury can import .tex, but it may require some editing, adding styles in Duxbury to the text is necessary to convert the text and math to the best formatted braille. I don't know enough about Tex files and packages to know if styles can be added to the document that import properly into Duxbury, but a simple document with basic text and math equations can be imported into Duxbury, converted directly to Braille and proper Nemeth code and be readable in braille, straight away. The more complex the document the more formatting and styles will be necessary to get useful braille output. Braille readers would appreciate the use of code for bridging text in math sections to reduce the number of indicator symbols for starting and ending a math section. Especially for content with math symbols throughout text sections. It's better to reduce the number of "start nemeth" and "end nemeth" indicators by bridging one and two words within math sections.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!