# Advanced Math and braille

Tags: equations, amsmath, subequations, amssymb, braille

How does one go about typesetting math books in braille with all parenthesized subscripts and superscripts and are there braille signs for the `amsmath` package special symbols?

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32685/2891

Comment: Did you looked at [Nicola Talbot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot)'s [ressource page](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latexresources.html#access)?

Comment: i don't know the answer to this, but there is a quite good blog post entitled "[Nemeth Braille Alphanumerics and Unicode Math Alphanumerics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2016/08/26/nemeth-braille-alphanumerics-and-unicode-math-alphanumerics/)" by the microsoft development engineer who i worked with in adding (thousands of) math symbols to unicode.  his conclusion is that 12-dot braille would be required to distinguish all the symbols identified for math, and that would be "really hard to learn".

Comment: I love these resources, and don't want to be complacent, but I think learning Braille by touch rather than by memorizing the pin positions by eyesight and then feeling out the pins might lead to a different experience. But before this one must at least be able to configure their phone or tablet and their braille device properly, and Android doesn't seem to do this yet, which is frustrating .

Comment: I have bookmarked your comments, and promise to return to them once I get my hands on a Braille enabled device that works properly our at least a voice powered device which is friendly from a (blind) accessibility perspective.

Comment: i have found a set of slides on the topic of [nemeth vs. ueb braille for stem presentation](http://accessibility.pearson.com/braille4math-science/Nemeth-UEB-Comparison.pdf) that claims the nemeth code contains more symbols than unicode or the stix fonts.  a contact address is given, and i intend to pursue this.

Comment: Maybe relevant, the PreTeXt project has been working on this, see https://aimath.org/aimnews/braille/: "As for the math formulas, they are represented using the Nemeth Braille Code which are produced by MathJax..."

Comment: Typesetting math books in braille requires specialized software and equipment. There are several software programs available, such as Duxbury Braille Translator and BrailleBlaster, that can convert mathematical notation in standard text format to braille.

Comment: In braille, parenthesized subscripts and superscripts are typically represented using a combination of braille symbols. For example, a subscript enclosed in parentheses would be represented by the symbol for an open parenthesis, followed by the braille symbol for the subscript, and then the symbol for a close parenthesis. Similarly, a superscript enclosed in parentheses would be represented by the symbol for an open parenthesis, followed by the braille symbol for the superscript, and then the symbol for a close parenthesis.

Comment: The American Mathematical Society (AMS) has developed a set of braille codes for some of the special symbols used in the amsmath package, including symbols for integrals, summations, and matrices. These codes can be found in the AMS publication "Braille Mathematics Notation: A Guide for Users".

Comment: I think this is an interesting topic. Would be nice, if someone could post a simple demo as solution, summarizing at least the comments made. Thank you.

Comment: @VincentKrebs -- Do you have a link for the publication "Braille Mathematics Notation"?  I'm not familiar with it, and can't find it on the AMS website.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501325/map-all-ascii-characters-in-document-to-nemeth-braille