# Map all ASCII characters in document to Nemeth Braille

Tags: luatex, fontspec, font-encodings

My goal is to type regular LaTeX input, and remap the fonts to produce Nemeth Braille.  One answer to the question [LaTeX to Braille](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32609/latex-to-braille)
was to download the font http://www.searchfreefonts.com/free/braille.htm .  This doesn't work for me because this font doesn't map (by default) ASCII characters the same way as Nemeth Braille.  For instance using that font, 0 and 9 become ⠔ and ⠯ instead of ⠴ and ⠔ respectively.
Furthermore, in any case I'd like to be able to map, in some cases, an individual ASCII character to a pair of Braille characters.

I tried using the font handling features of luatex to make substitutions.  They didn't seem to have any effect for the font mentioned in the answer above, but they did for DejaVu.

Here's what I tried:

```
% -*- TeX-engine: luatex; -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "braille",
    type = "substitution", 
    data = {
      ["a"] = "⠁", ["b"] = "⠃", ["c"] = "⠉",
      % etc. all the way to z
      ["A"] = {"⠠","⠁"}, ["B"] = {"⠠","⠃"},
      ["C"] = {"⠠","⠉"}, % etc. all the way to Z
    }}}        


\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "combos",
    type = "multiple", 
    data = {
      ["="] = {" ","⠨","⠅"," "}, 
      ["X"] = {"⠠","⠭"}, 
      ["Y"] = {"⠠","⠽"},
    }}}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}[RawFeature=+braille;+combos]
\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}
abc = ABC = XY 

$abc\ =\ ABC\ =\ XY$  % should be identical to previous line
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of MWE]

What still doesn't work:  (1) The font feature of type `substitution` doesn't let me replace one character of input with two characters of output (or I don't know how to make it do this).  So A, B, and C are incorrect in both lines. (2) The font feature of type `multiple` does allow one input go to two output characters, but it's not inherited by the math fonts using the mathastext package (or I don't know how to make it do this). So =, X and Y are incorrect in the math line.

Does anyone know how to get the remapping to work for either DejaVu or the Braille font mentioned above?

**Update**
If I add to the MWE above (plus quite a few more substitutions) I get this:

```
And now we can conclude that
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}/2
$$
Here it is with better Nemeth
$$
\int_0^\infty\baseline e^{-x^^2}\baseline \,dx \eq \sqrt{\pi}/2
$$
```

and here is the output

[image: Longer sample Nemeth code]

The first version of the equation is unmodified LaTeX code, but with all the substitutions and commands translated.  I think it's not a bad start.

The second one requires the author to make a few changes: indicating when a subscript/superscript is over, and indicating when there's a double superscript, and I used a command for the equals sign (because, as mentioned above, I couldn't get the combination substitution to work).  My guess is that more of the latex code could be automated, requiring fewer changes by the author (especially with Luatex?).  But it's still not horrible to imagine adding the extra markup to make the Nemeth more accurate.

Comment: Can we assume that the font will only be used in math mode?

Comment: I don't think it is that simple to convert LaTeX math to Nemeth. See the article by Susan Jolly in the [recent TugBoat](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb40-1/tb124jolly-braille.pdf). She wrote MathML to Nemeth convertor in Java, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: The font will be used in both main text and math.

Comment: True, it's not that simple.  But the first step, for me, would be to map all the ASCII characters.  After that, the basic macros are quite easy. With that, an author could do basic math if they are willing to add/change their markup.  Things like tables and matrices would be harder.  

In any case, at present, I have something that works up to a point, and what's not working is mapping single ASCII characters to pairs of Braille, and someone who knows fonts and/or Luatex probably knows what I could change.

Comment: multiple substituations don't work with the mode=base used in math. But beside this I'm not convinced that the general idea is sound. Imho you will run into problems as soon as  \int, or \frac or limits/superscripts etc are involved.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike.  I appreciate your expertise here.  

I'm sure you are correct, but sometimes I feel like trying things even though they will not probably work all the way.  I mean, for me at least, even a solution that is only 75% good, and requires a little extra work, might be useful.  See update above.

Comment: If you accept specific markup why use math at all? The main point of math is to get a very fine tuned visual output, a text mode environment is much more suited for the output you want. You then only need to give commands like \int etc sensible definitions. Btw: don't use $$ for display math. At first it is not latex and at second it is difficult to manipulate. With \[..\] you could redefine the commands. And ping me with @UlrikeFischer,  "Ulrike" won't work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks again, I'll give it a try as you suggest, basically getting rid of math mode entirely (i.e. redefining \( \) and \[ and \]).  Originally I thought the least amount of rewriting would be to work within math mode, but you've convinced me that this may not be the case.

Comment: I added an answer to mapping to Braille at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32609/latex-to-braille/511163#511163 Perhaps it should go here.

Answer (score 4):

Here, I use `tokcycle` to parse the input and transform characters (and the macro `\eq`) into braille.  However, it the course of doing this, I discovered a bug in my `tokcycle` package, in that it was not digesting `=` tokens properly. The fix, detailed in the postscript, is also incorporated into the MWE.

EDIT: To demonstrate how macros can be remapped in the same way as characters, I mapped the `\eq` macro to take on the desired meaning of what would otherwise be the `=` token.  Macros can be mapped in this way without destroying their original meaning outside of the `\braille` pseudo-environment.

By automatically wrapping the braille mappings in a `\textrm{}`, the issue of math mode becomes moot, except that spaces are intercepted in math mode and converted to explicit `\`  spacing.

Compiled here with lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}%[RawFeature=+braille;+combos]
%\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\tokcycleenvironment\braille%  NEW TOKCYCLE ENVIRONMENT:
{\addcytoks[4]{\tcremap{##1}}}%   HOW TO TREAT CHARACTERS
{\processtoks{##1}}%              HOW TO TREAT GROUP CONTENTS
{\addcytoks[4]{\tcremap{##1}}}%   HOW TO TREAT MACROS
{\addcytoks{\ }}%                 HOW TO TREAT SPACES
\newcommand*\tcmapto[2]{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto\string#1\endcsname{\textrm{#2}}}
\newcommand*\tcremap[1]{\ifcsname tcmapto\string#1\endcsname
  \csname tcmapto\string#1\expandafter\endcsname\else\expandafter#1\fi}
\tcmapto a{⠁} \tcmapto b{⠃} \tcmapto c{⠉} 
\tcmapto A{⠠⠁} \tcmapto B{⠠⠃} \tcmapto C{⠠⠉}
\tcmapto X{⠠⠭} \tcmapto Y{⠠⠽} \tcmapto ={ ⠨⠨ } 
\tcmapto\eq{ ⠨⠨ }% MACRO REMAPS DONE SIMILARLY
\def\eq{EQ}% NON-BRAILLE DEFINITION
\begin{document}
1. \braille abc = ABC = XY\endbraille

2. \braille$abc = ABC = XY$\endbraille  % should be identical to previous line

3. \braille abc \eq{} ABC \eq{} XY\endbraille

4. \braille$abc \eq{} ABC \eq{} XY$\endbraille  % should be identical to previous line

%\detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}

$\eq$ reverts to non-braille
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't had time to play with this recently, but I'll check it out soon.  It looks like a good approach.