# Strange appearance of tooltips produced by pdfcomment

Tags: pdf, pdfcomment

Tooltips can be generated with [`pdfcomment`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) package. However, they lead to some weird behavior if one clicks on a tooltiped item: the item becomes highlighted and "checked" (checked in Acrobat Reader 9 in Debian and Acrobat Reader X in Windows XP). So, it looks more like a "checkbox":

[image: tooltip, with tooltip area highlighted and ticked]

See an example below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment} 

\newcommand\MyShortCut[3]{\newcommand{#1}{\pdftooltip{#2}{#3}}}

\MyShortCut{\textthing}{tooltip here}{just an example}
\MyShortCut{\Td}{\tau_\textrm{d}}{reptation time}
\MyShortCut{\Tr}{\tau_\textrm{R}}{Rouse time}

\begin{document}
Use pdflatex to compile, then open in Acrobat Reader and
put the mouse pointer above $\tau$'s

\[
\Td = 3 Z \Tr
\]

Or in text \textthing.

\end{document}
```

Question: is there a better way to achieve my goal: to have a tooltip when a mouse pointer is over a piece of text or a variable? Without any side effects, like the ones described above. Ideally, with `hyperref` only, so I do not need to load extra packages (`\href` does something similar).

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32314/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-hover-text-to-all-incidents-of-math-mode-where-the-h

Comment: @Marco Daniel : Thanks for the tip. I saw that question but it does not solve the problem. Actually, the `pdfcomment` example there suffers from the same phenomenon as I have explained above.

Comment: I this post the package `fancytooltips` is listed. Is this package an alternative?

Comment: @Marco Daniel : No, `fancytooltips` is not an alternative, because of two points. First of all, it would be really an overkill for simple text-only tooltips I need. Secondly, it works only with Javascript enabled in AcroRead, whereas simple tooltips I need is a feature of PDF, which does not require Javascript (due to security reasons, it is a good idea to switch off Javascript in AcroRead, what many people, including myself, do).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This bug has been fixed in version 2.3a of `pdfcomment`, which is available [on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) and can be obtained by updating your TeX distribution. The manual fix provided in this answer is not necessary any more!

Apparently there's a bug in [`pdfcomment`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) which causes the weird appearance of the tooltips: There is a spurious slash in the specification of the field flags ([`pdfcomment.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfcomment/pdfcomment.sty), l. 2967), so Adobe Reader uses the default value for this property and creates a checkbox instead of the desired pushbutton. The following example includes a fix for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
% Fix incorrect display of tooltips (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74340/3323)
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\pc@annot@tooltip}%
{%
  /TU (\pc@pdfenc@contents)\space%
  /T (tooltip \thezref@unique)\space%
  /C [0 0 0]\space%
  /FT/Btn\space%
  /Ff 65536\space%
  /H/N\space%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\MyShortCut[3]{\newcommand{#1}{\pdftooltip{#2}{#3}}}

\MyShortCut{\textthing}{tooltip here}{just an example}
\MyShortCut{\Td}{\tau_\textrm{d}}{reptation time}
\MyShortCut{\Tr}{\tau_\textrm{R}}{Rouse time}

\begin{document}
Use pdflatex to compile, then open in Acrobat Reader and
put the mouse pointer above $\tau$'s

\[
\Td = 3 Z \Tr
\]

Or in text \textthing.

\end{document}
```

#### Tooltip appearance:

[image: tooltip without strange highlighting or checkboxes]

Like this, no strange boxes are shown around the tooltip area on hover, and it's not possible to highlight or tick it.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the sources - and understanding them ;-) So the different behaviour of other PDF readers may also caused of this. Some one needs to inform Josef Kleber (@josef here on TeX.sx).

Comment: Josef is informed ;-) There's a bugfix version at Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/kleberj/pdfcomment/raw/b5bf3fe6ece7/dev/tex/latex/pdfcomment/pdfcomment.sty  There will be a new release to Bitbucket and CTAN soon!

Comment: @Josef: Oh, nice. Say him thank you! ;-)