# zooming with mouse over

Tags: pdftex

I am looking for existing codes for magnifying pre-defined  portions of text in PDF the output of LaTeX. The applications is for accessibility for the visually impaired, so from users' point of view minimizing number of clicks and mouse movements is essential. From content providers' point of view simplicity of coding is important. 
A feature like the one MathJax has is desirable:  set magnification factor, activate by mouse over, deactivate by mouse away, or similar settings. 
I am aware of the following  [Hover](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32314/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-hover-text-to-all-incidents-of-math-mode-where-the-h) and [ZoomBox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12290/automatic-zoom-in-hypertext-boxes-in-pdf). Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: To me, it looks like a problem you should solve in the PDF viewer, not in (La)TeX.

Comment: This looks like a viewer issues, as @FedericoPoloni says. As such, and especially without a clue as to the viewer in question, I think this is off-topic.