# How to embed a vegalite graph/plot into latex beamer presentation?

Tags: pdftex, overleaf

I want to add a vegalite plot into my presentation in the overleaf beamer template. Which package should be used and what is the process and commands for adding a vegalite plot in the overleaf beamer template?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you create a plot with a program (Vega-Lite) outsite of LaTeX it's best to export it as a vector file (e.g. pdf or svg) that can be importet into LaTeX again.

Comment: Answer: [Vega-Lite - Create Figures for Papers](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/tutorials/figures.html)

Comment: Thanks, but in such a case, the hover information is no more accessible.

Comment: I am trying to add these plots: https://wispo-pop.github.io/PowerPlots.jl/stable/

Comment: I don't think that there is any ready to use solution that export those files with hover information to LaTeX. While it is possible to add hover information / tooltips (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32314/123129)), it might be complicated. If the reader prints the resulting pdf it would also be useless. Than it would be better to link to some online source as additional information.

Comment: Thanks, @dexteritas