# voting via pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, javascript

Can one use a pdf file output of pdflatex as a ballot and vote counter?

I am looking for a ballot.tex file such that ballot.pdf will have the following properties:

There are boxes of choices A,B,C,D,E, etc on it

If a viewer clicks on a box, say A, a counter next to it goes up by one

If another viewer clicks on the same box the counter again goes up by one

If the a viewer clicks on the same box twice, the second vote will cancel the original vote.

(Assume every voter has access to only one computer.)

Comment: I imagine this would be useful: [Example of Javascript form within pdflatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30706/5764)

Comment: Related: [Techniques of Introducing Document-level JavaScript into a PDF file from a LaTeX Source](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-3/tb72story.pdf)