# How to make interactive PDF documents with TeX?

Tags: pdf

Is it possible to have an interactive PDF Document using LaTeX?
For example, I want to make a PDF document (math exercise sheets) such that:

- The user could  fold/unfold parts of the document (i.e., the user could press a plus to see  the answers)
- The user could tick some field to submit an answer and see his/her score
- Print the resulting PDF document or save it

Comment: related question/partial duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/constructing-a-dynamic-pdf

Comment: This would be limited to acrobat and acrobat reader. Some of this is probably not yet possible even so. Documents with this amount of dynamic content are better suited to web pages with javascript. This would be better for the submission process as well, if you use a dose of CGI.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8918/hello-world-in-pdflatex (talking pdf!) and interactive http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7869/how-do-you-say-happy-new-year-with-latex. Only work with acrobat.

Comment: I like this animated Tikz texample of a Wankel motor: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/wankel-motor/

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to have an interactive `PDF` document, but will only probably work in Acrobat Reader. Some examples can be found at [Hello World in pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8918/hello-world-in-pdflatex) and [How do you say Happy New Year with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7869/how-do-you-say-happy-new-year-with-latex).

There are a number of ways to create them but the simpler so far is to use the [insdljs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/insdljs) package from the [AcroTeX Education Bundle](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex/doc/aeb_man.pdf).

To create the interactive part one needs to use PFD Forms and to insert the appropriate JavaScript code, which like in web pages is used to script the interactive part.

The `insdljs` package provides an environment, similar to file contents for writing a JavaScript file. In the minimal it defines a function to calculate the area and diameter of a circle given its radius.

```javascript
function doCalculation()
{
    var radius=0.0 + this.getField("radius").value;
    this.getField("diameter").value=radius*2;
    this.getField("areacircle").value=  Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
}
```

The Textfields and push button are also defined accordingly. The MWE illustrates the application. Please view it with a compatible reader.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled =.92]{helvet}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{5.2075in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{4.90in}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{phv}
\usepackage[pdftex,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{A Sample Calculation}\chead{}
\rhead{Area of Circle}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{}\rfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex,pdfpagelayout=SinglePage,
pdftitle={Wishing you a happy year},pdfsubject={Invest your new year improving your TeX skills}%
]{hyperref}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}


\begin{insDLJS}[test]{test}{JavaScript}
function doCalculation()
{
var radius=0.0 + this.getField("radius").value;
 this.getField("diameter").value=radius*2;
 this.getField("areacircle").value=  Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
}
\end{insDLJS}

%% Short hand commands
\newcommand{\textforlabel}[2]{%
\TextField[name={#1}, value={#2}, width=9em,align=2,%
               bordercolor={0.990 .980 .85},%
               readonly=true]{}%
}


%% Define the heading
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\Huge Calculations\\ with JavaScript\\*[4pt] and pdfLateX!}
\end{center}

\newpage

\begin{Form}

\heading{Area of Circle}

%% 
%%% Input field radius

\textforlabel{l01}{Radius:}
\TextField[name=radius,width=10em, bordercolor={0.650 .790 .94}]{}%
~m\\

%% Push button is defined here
\textforlabel{l02}{Press to calculate}  
\PushButton[name=start,onclick={doCalculation();},bordercolor={0.650 .790 .94}%
]{Calculate}\\ 

\heading{Results}\\

%% RESULTS
%% Diameter
\textforlabel{name=l04}{%
Diameter :} \TextField[name=diameter,width=10em,bordercolor={0.650 .790 .94},%
readonly=true]{}~m

\textforlabel{name=l05}{Area:}  
\TextField[name=areacircle,width=10em,%
bordercolor={0.650 .790 .94},readonly=true]{}~m$^2$\\*[-0.8em]
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

The [AcroTeX Education Bundle](http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex/doc/aeb_man.pdf) provides numerous other functions, which can be useful in an Academic environment for quizzes and tutorials.

Personally I am not very convinced, as such facilities can better be provided in web pages with better interactivity and opening other opportunities.

Comment: Several viewers support enough of the Adobe object model to support Interactive PDF, including Apple's Preview application and Safari browser.  Interactive PDFs are quite useful for adding navigation support to documents, e.g. having pop-ups in the index that show the context of the references listed for each entry.

Comment: @CharlesStewart Very true.

Comment: New Address: http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex/doc/aeb_man.pdf