# Can LaTeX create underlines on mouse hover?

Tags: links

[Example](http://www.documentgeek.com/blog/1-inline-buttons/hyperlink-in-text.pdf) created from InDesign

[Indesign tutorial](http://documentgeek.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/inline-buttons.html)

Can we do this in LaTeX, possibly with an underline as opposed to a text background fill (although in principle anything would be possible)? It's possible in PDFs so it should be possible in principle.

Comment: These links might be of help:

[How to make interactive PDF documents with TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45106/how-to-make-interactive-pdf-documents-with-tex) and 

[Interactive PDF, Latex and Article of the Future](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84681/interactive-pdf-latex-and-article-of-the-future)

Comment: I would so love to put a bounty on this question, but in its current state, it's IMHO too poorly written to deserve one.

Comment: Can you tell me how to improve it? I have absolutely no idea.