# A mask for conversion degrees to radians and viceversa for my students of an high school

Tags: calculations, acrotex

Starting from this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\DEGtoRAD{60}{\sola}
Result in radian without the use $\pi$: \sola
\RADtoDEG{1}{\solb}
Result in degree without the use of the symbol $^\circ$: \solb
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wanted to create a "mask" where in input they can put the angle in degree and in output they will have the result in radiant with the presence of the `\pi` symbol and viceversa. The `.pdf` file must contain the mask where my students can put the values.

*Is it possible to do this "interactive mask" using `calculator` package associated with `AcroTeX` or another solution?*

I not know `AcroTeX`. Thank you very much.

**Addendum:** I have now found this very nice link:

https://www.mathportal.org/calculators/trigonometry-calculators/degrees-to-radians-converter.php

Comment: Please have a look at [How to make interactive PDF documents with TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45106/how-to-make-interactive-pdf-documents-with-tex). That might help you.

Comment: @Typo Now I remember it was AcroTeX written of an american citizen. Now I not remember your name. Thank you for the link... I have read now...it is D. P. Story. :-) If I must create a code, sure, it is necessary one year :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Alessandro Cuttin for your editing.